# changing date format in javascript dynamically in userside

Tags: javascript

how to change date format dynamically in clientside using javascript..as i cant change it in serverside..say jsps..as these things meeds 2 b changed frequently.

i am using eclipse,j2ee,jscript

Answer (score 2):

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("m/dd/yy");
// Returns, e.g., 6/09/07
```

- [Here is very good article with example](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)